# PowerApps out of office different user

Tags: office365, powerapps

I have a feeling this can't be done easily, and would likely require some PowerShell scripting. but here goes:

I'm looking for a way for line managers to be able to turn their direct reports' out of office on if they call in sick. Something I can add to the Sharepoint site would be great as everything is then in one place.

Powerapps appear to offer a pretty good place to start, but it looks like the Office365 connector is linked to the user currently logged in, so getting the calendar ID using:

```
LookUp(Office365.CalendarGetTables().value,DisplayName = "Calendar").Name
```

will only ever return the user's own calendar id. CalendarGetTables() does not accept any parameters, so passing a user id or UPN results in an error.

I can totally see the security issue that would be caused were it so simple.

Does anyone know of a different solution? As the only admin here, I'd like to make this a self-service for managers to sort out their own direct reports.